# Ideal image size for Fullpage.JS background image

Tags: html, css, image, fullpage.js

I am using fullpage.js to create parallax website, however I am thinking of the ideal image size that I can use for background image in every section.

If the image is too big it will cost more loading time, but when the image is so small it might sacrifice the quality of the images, so I am looking for the ideal image size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of [CSS 3 media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/CSS/Media_queries) to load one or another background image depending on the resolution of the viewport.

This will help a lot when loading the site in mobile devices and won't load huge images for small laptops.

Additionally you can load the backgrounds dynamically using [this lazy load technique](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js/issues/46#issuecomment-26509996). This way you won't load images in sections which are not visible.

Answer (score 1):

You can use images based on ratio 16:9 which is usuall 1.777 Units to 1 unit. a very good reasonable size can be 1920 x 1080 Saved for web from photoshop or any other software also 1440 x 900 is a good size but you will find it a bit blurry on 21" plus screens

Comment: How about the small devices? Big images can prevent smaller devices from seeing the full image.

Comment: You Should use the @media queries in order to make your img responsive and fluid